# RSpec: how to supress of variable's caching

Tags: ruby, rspec

I haven't much experience with RSpec and I'm not going to spread about a real task, but if the problem that I encountered will much simplified, it looks like this:

```
    describe "Test" do
      context "ctx_1" do
        before(:all) do
          # Changes of $x from "nil" to a some NOT an earlier predefined instance.
          # A real case supposes getting this variable from other execution part.
          # It is very essential. 
          $x = [1, 2, 3] 
        end

        $x.each do |e|
          context "ctx_2"
            before (:all) do
              puts "do a some things for #{e}"  
            end

            it "example #{$x.index(e)}" do
              puts "do some checking for #{e}"
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Is there any way to wrap "ctx 2" to the loop with a fresh $x value without its cashing value (nil)?
The problem is the updated value of $x works only within "it" blocks. Any variation with another entytyes (@ instead of $, describe, context, before etc.) doesn't pass..

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do but you shouldn't use global variables.

Comment: heve you tried with `let` ?

Comment: Yes I have it with let, !let instead of before, but there is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have some confusion about how and when your code runs:

- `before` blocks run *just before a test runs*.
- The `context` block runs in the test *declaration* phase - a lot earlier, much earlier than when you assign `$x`.

That is why when you do `$x.each` you get 'nil' as the `$x` value. The `$x.each` loop will *never* run *after* the `before` block, so you will need to redesign your code.

You can maybe set `$x` as part of your configuration in `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: If I right understand, the redesign you suggest, supposes to refuse from wrap of "context{ it {}}" blocks into $x.each cycle.. But it is key moment of my script. Another words I have to get some x-collection   in begin of running test, then perform some steps (actions, checks, etc.) with this collection later at the another part of the test. Unfortunately it seems impossible so far.

Comment: You can perform the logic from within a single test (test in a loop over `$x`) instead of building separate tests for each

Comment: I'm affraid it is impossible because I don't know $x.count before that tests will be run.

Comment: Should not matter, as you will always have _one_ test which runs them all (it will fail when the first one fails, but you'll know if all have passed)

Comment: You right. I had reviewed also as an alternative to put a cycle into one "it {}" block. It works. But in my case each test is a complex set of actions, each of that involves a several examples at least. I had tryed this way, but nested examples (it {} blocks) is forbidden in RSpec (unlike nested describe & context blocks).